# Same functions return algebraically differently gives value at certain point for certain form?

Tags: abstract-algebra, limits, derivatives

Same functions return algebraically differently gives the value at a certain point for a certain form but undefined at other forms, Why is that? I can see algebraically why that's the case but intuitively I couldn't get it. could someone give me some insight or point me to the proper resource would be great.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The last expression does not define the "*same function*", because it does not have the same domain as the first two. In particular, it is defined at $x=1$ whereas the other two are not.

Comment: thanks @dxiv. but my question is why does the domain change? because we just writing the same function in a different way correct?

Comment: thanks, @dxiv seems exactly what i need